# 16.04 corrupted mysql after update

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

After update a few days ago my mysql installation is corrupted.

I completely removed everything from mysql and tried to install it again, getting the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am scared of mysql updates now, one updated screwed all database system...

Comment: How's your backup?

Comment: There is probably a more informative error somewhere, perhaps in systemd or apt logs, or just a bit higher up in the terminal.

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install ?